# Chrome Plugin: change page web source?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I would like to know, how would I go about changing a webpage source code? I am basically, trying to build a real-time chat translator for facebook.

I would like to do this programmatically, you can change the website source in Chrome, manually and the changes show up. I would like to do the same with a plug-in.

And, is this the best way of going about this problem? or, Does Facebook offer any Chat API, which will facilitate the task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

It makes possible to change web page. You can inject javascript. so that you're probably able to modify the content of facebook chat 'div' dom.